# Hide another div within same parent with jQuery

Tags: jquery, find, parent

I have this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

I want to toggle the div 2 when I click the div 1 within the same parent. I have more divs of the same kind (I generate those on click dynamically) so I needed to use classes. 
I don't know how to do this. What I've made:

```
$('.1').click(function (e) {
  var elementFound = $(this).find('.2');
  elementFound.toggle('fade', 500);
}
```

It's not working, but I think this is searching for the div with the class 2 within the div with the class 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your class names are invalid. In CSS, class names [may not start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). I've modified them slightly below.

If the other div is always a sibling, you can use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings):

```
$('.x1').click(function (e) {
    $(this).siblings('.x2').toggle('fade', 500);
});
```

If it may not be a sibling, but is within that same parent, you can use a combination of [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
$('.x1').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.x2').toggle('fade', 500);
});
```

Comment: I know, it was just an example. Thank you for your answer!